# Refresh data inside a div

Tags: jquery, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I have a phonegap app built with framework7 that has a '[pull to refresh](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/pull-to-refresh.html#.VSAJ1EYX3IZ)' option.

This is the function that activates the pull to refesh:

```
        // Pull to refresh content
        var ptrContent = $$('.pull-to-refresh-content');

        // Add 'refresh' listener on it
        ptrContent.on('refresh', function (e) {
            // Emulate 2s loading
            setTimeout(function () {

                $( ".content-block" ).empty();

                // Refresh the data from url
                // reload the .content-block div

myApp.pullToRefreshDone();
            }, 1000);
        });
```

I need the .content-block div to reload with new data from this [url](http://incinerationfest.blogspot.co.uk/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=posts) after its emptied .

Not sure how to do that - the function above works as the .content-block is emptied after the pull.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do an AJAX call, and then use its output, in this case, insert into .content-block.

You can read more on AJAX here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here is some sample code:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://..."
}).done(function(data) {
    // The 'data' variable will contain the json data returned, which you may loop with a foreach loop and convert it into html blocks
    var contentBlock = ""; // This variable will contain your html
    $(".content-block").html(contentBlock);
});
```